# Сложение  разных  типов Java, что на  выходе?

Tags: java

Господа  извиняюсь  за  возможно  за  глупый  вопрос, и  всеж задам  его - что получится  если  сложить  double  и  int?

Заранее  благодарю)))

Comment: простите, а что вам мешает самому это проверить?

Comment: Хороший  ответ)))
Просто есть код
double a = 1.56;
int c = 5;
int d = 3;
b = (int)(a+c+d);
пришел 0
если  убрать  приведение  типа то  вообще  ни  чего  не приходит

Comment: Я  так  понимаю  для  меня  будет  выходом
b = ((int)(a)) + c + d;

Comment: а что такое b у вас?

Comment: int b = 0;

Comment: @alexmx это не глупый вопрос :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

при сложении int и double результатом будет double, поскольку double имеет больший диапазон, нежели int. В вашем случае вы помещаете результат (который, еще раз напомню, имеет тип double) в целочисленную переменную. Разумеется int не может хранить числа с плавающей точкой, поэтому в b сохранится округленное число. и числом этим будет 9, а не 0, как вы указали. 
[Пример](http://ideone.com/YrA0q3)

Answer (score 7):

вот шпаргалка что куда и как можно приводить (взял у Хорстманна):

-сплошная линия -  приведение без потерь.

-штриховая - при приведении возможны потери.

в остальных случаях требуется явное приведение (скобочками)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

При сложении получится double. Если я правильно помню, в арифметических операциях если хоть один операнд имеет тип double, остальные операнды приводятся в double и на выходе в итоге double. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: похоже  что не так, так  как убрав  приведение  к  int  вообще  ни  чего  не  пришло

Comment: У вас b - переменная типа int. Попробуйте при выводе через System.out.println() явно указать рассчитываемое выражение. Если будет точка в выводимом числе - это double. И вы увидите, что результат double. А в int оно округлится.